# Mediawiki integrating with existing site

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Hi to all i'm having the site which is fully having the video contents in it. What i want to do is i have to integrate mediawiki pages with my site. I have downloaded the mediawiki package and i have installed in in my system.Now i want to display the video files which is from my site using my own player in site. But the site functionalities should be like the mediawiki like. That means if any users access my page and edit it means it should be saved in media wiki history. Is that possible to use the media wiki functionalities in  our site.Please suggest me any solutions.

Comment: That sounds complicated. I'd suggest replacing your site with the wiki, creating a custom skin for it and writing an extension that integrates your video player into mediawiki

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your reply bergi But we are using other operations apart from the mediawiki in our site. So if we are using mediawiki those operations will affect. so is possible to integrate at least the database to our site database?

Comment: That sounds complicated. Could you tell us more about your site, and what operations it does?

Comment: @Bergi We are having the site which is having the operations streaming,video recording,live streaming and video editing so far.Any user can register and do the recording,saving and editing their videos.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you want to do from the description you gave, but this might be interesting: http://www.kaltura.org/project/metavid_semantic_wiki_extension

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page).

But it's much easier and probably also a lot cleaner to stick with including [rendered](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?action=render&title=MediaWiki) pages from MediaWiki and sending people who want to edit to MediaWiki. When including rendered pages it's good to be aware of duplicate content issues (SEO).